# After adding the item to the array how refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

After adding the item to the array.it is not show means not render.

i am try myself but no success

my code It below you can run it online

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TouchableOpacity,ScrollView} from 'react-native';
  

export default function App({navigation}) {
   const [dummyarray, setDummyarray] = useState([{id:1, product:"pendrive"}]);

async function addiem(){
dummyarray.push({id:2, product:"mobile phone"})
}

   return (
       <View  >
 <ScrollView>    

{dummyarray.map((item,idx) => (
            <View key={idx} style={{  backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
       <Text>{item.product}</Text>                
            </View>
    ))}


<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>addiem()}><Text>Clear all orders</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
 </ScrollView>
   </View>
    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

React change detection works on immutability and by `dummyarray.push(...)` you are mutating the array so React cannot register the change. You have to use the setter you get from `useState` and copy the array in order to not mutate it. Like this:

`setDummyArray(prevArr => [...prevArr, {id:2, product:"mobile phone"}])`

Comment: Amazing. Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
async function addiem(){
   dummyarray.push({id:2, product:"mobile phone"})
 }
```

This is wrong, you **can't** update a state like this !
You can use for example `...` spread syntax

```
function addiem(){
  setDummyarray.push(current => [...current, {id:2, product:"mobile phone"}])
}
```

Comment: This works for me. Thank you very much.